# Convert timestamp column to float minutes pandas python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns contains timestamps as:

```
    created
0   2020-05-27T14:00:00.000Z
1   2020-05-27T14:01:00.000Z
2   2020-05-27T14:01:00.000Z
3   2020-05-27T14:02:00.000Z
4   2020-05-27T14:02:00.000Z
... ...
992 2020-05-28T11:57:00.000Z
995 2020-05-28T11:58:00.000Z
997 2020-05-28T11:59:00.000Z
996 2020-05-28T11:59:00.000Z
998 2020-05-28T11:59:00.000Z
```

I would like to transform all this column to floats with the amount of minutes passed after the first event; for example

```
    created
0   0.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   2.0
4   2.0
... ...
and so on.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to `datetime`, subtract and divide by minutes:

```
df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created'])
df['created'] = (df['created'] - df['created'].iloc[0])/pd.to_timedelta('1Min')
```

Output:

```
     created
0        0.0
1        1.0
2        1.0
3        2.0
4        2.0
992   1317.0
995   1318.0
997   1319.0
996   1319.0
998   1319.0
```